# Position of Dynamically Created DIV within other Created Buttons

Tags: javascript

I have a DIV being created with Javascript that a slideshow is going into. Everything works great, execpt the positioning of this DIV. I want it to be further down the page, but no matter where I put the document.write that creates it, the DIV remains at the top in Firefox & Chrome. For IE, it doesn't display unless the code is at the top of my script. Any suggestions or fixes?

```
writeButton("","/page1.html","light_box_b01",206,298,"","",0);
writeButton("","/page2.html","light_box_b02b",206,84,"","",0);
document.write('<div id="fadeshow1" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;"></div>')
writeButton("","/page3.html","light_box_b03b",206,89,"","",0);
writeButton("","/page4.html","closeout",206,78,"","",0);

document.write("<td><img src=\""+loc+"Separator02"+gtype+"\" alt=\"\" width=\"206\" height=\"35\"></td>");

document.write('<div id="fadeshow1" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;"></div>')
writeButton("","/page5.html","p_ClipFrame",206,20,"Clip Frames","",0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an example that adds an image to div on the page. One uses jQuery the other just plain JavaScript. You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/j6dZf/

```
// example 1: using normal javascript

// create a variable with the image url (not required)
var src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/af/Golden_retriever_eating_pigs_foot.jpg/170px-Golden_retriever_eating_pigs_foot.jpg";

// remember id's must be unique per page
// here i'm taking the container div and saving it
var container = document.getElementById("container");

// here i create a new image, set the src attribute and append to container
var img = new Image();
img.src = src;
container.appendChild(img);
```

This is the jQuery Version

```
// example 2: using jquery
$(function() { // usually you wrap jQuery in this sort of thing
    var $container = $("#container") // grab container using jQuery
    var $img = $("<img>", {src: src}); // create an image tag with src set
    $container.append($img); // add the image you create, could just add text
})
```

Comment: Hi Jamund thank you for all the information. I'm going to try this method because it's a bit cleaner. What I ended up going with with using document.write to create an empty td between the two buttons that I wanted to place the slideshow between, and the absolutely positioning the slideshow in that empty space so it wasn't just on top of everything. I am familiar with CSS, just not javascript. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `document.write` but rather `document.createElement` and then append the resulting structures to the document with `appendChild`. You'll have much better results.

You also should be controlling where the item displays on the page with CSS. You can either assign these programmatically via JavaScript or you can provide classes and ids and link them to a pre-defined CSS stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so let's see here. Here are a couple of suggestions/questions. Hopefully one or two of them will help.

1. Why are you using `document.write()`?
2. Why do you have inline CSS? Is it possible you can separate it?
3. What does the `writeButton()` function do?
4. Are you using anything like jQuery that might make your DOM work easier?
5. You should only have an ID once on the same page! It appears you are adding it twice.
6. What do you mean by "further down the page"?
7. Have you thought about using `position: absolute`, which will give you more power to move the `<div>` around within the page?
8. You can put the `<div>` in another place in the DOM by using `element.appendChild` instead of `document.write`. (See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.appendChild)

Comment: Thank you. document.write was just the method that seemed to work. I inherited this framework and have to work within it. I had the inline CSS to test it to make sure before editing the CSS for the page. The writebutton() display an image that then links to another page, there are about 10 there. JQuery is on the page, but I'm unfamilar. Two IDs was mistake.  Further down the page is placing it inbetween some of the writebuttons. Tried position: absolute, but it overlayed, I need it inbetween two writebuttons. It's all generated by .js, so appendChild may not work?

Comment: Hey @Justin there are a lot of things you can do to make your life simpler here! First off you need to become familiar with a little bit of basic CSS. You don't just set things to `position: absolute` and magically have it show up where you want. Instead you may need to define one or two other CSS properties `top` and `left`. You may also want to try `position: relative` in combination with those two properties. Here's a rather long-winded explanation of the various positioning options: http://htmldog.com/examples/positioning2.html.